# Let $H$ be a nontrivial subgroup of rationals under addition. Prove that $H$ has a nontrivial proper subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that $H\neq \{e\}$ since it is nontrivial.
This means $g\in H$ which means $g^{-1}\in H$ and $g^n\in H$.

Let $U$ be a subgroup of $H$. We know that $e,g \in U$ and therefore $g^{-1}\in U$ and $g^n\in U$.

> My question is where to go from here. So I am not sure how to show that there is an element in $H$ that is not in $U$.

Comment: It would make more sense to prove the much more general result that any group that is not cyclic of prime order has a nontrivial proper subgroup.

Answer (score 5):

We may assume that $H$ is generated by a single element, since if it is not we may look at the subgroup $\langle h \rangle\subset H$ for any non-identity element $h\in H$. But then we know that, since $H$ is generated by a single element, it is a cyclic group. What kind of cyclic group must $H$ be? What can you say about subgroups of cyclic groups?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(0\ne x)x\in H$ if $H\ne \langle x\rangle$ then $\langle x\rangle$ is desired proper subgroup.If $H=\langle x\rangle$ then consider $\langle 2x\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Assume that $n H = H$ for every $n$ natural anc conclude that $H= \mathbb{Q}$.